# What is Doom 2 game camera focal length?

Tags: doom-2

Many computer vision applications (including [SLAM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_NJxbkQnBU) for [VizDoom](http://vizdoom.cs.put.edu.pl/)) rely on camera information. So I'm wondering what is Doom 2's camera focal length?

Comment: Are you possibly referring to the field of view?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf: indeed I do http://kmp.bdimitrov.de/technology/fov.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no focal length as the game rendering doesn't use a sensor/film; same focal length lens will produce different FOV depending on sensor/film size.

Typical FOV of Doom is 90 degrees; following the [conversion table](https://www.nikonians.org/reviews/fov-tables) you're getting ~22mm if you assume 35mm/FX format, 14mm for DX format. Trying to use the screen diagonal doesn't make sense though.